# When do I use http attributes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, api, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

when making a c# controller,

- what is the difference between API controller and controller base?
- when using HTTP attributes?

My question is that there are controllers that don't use HTTP attributes and everything works fine, I was wondering how this controller distinguishes HTTP put, HTTP post and HTTP get? Why didn't they use HTTP attributes?
Knowing that it is an API controller.

Comment: what kind of project you are refering to? Razor Pages? MVC? API?

Comment: I am using vue.js for the client-side, and c# for the server-side, ASP.NET Core Web API

Answer (score 0):

`Web API Controller` is similar to ASP.NET MVC controller. It handles incoming HTTP requests and send response back to the caller. It must be derived from `System.Web.Http.ApiController` class.

`Base Controllers` are C# classes inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`, which is the builtin controller base class.

The Controller knows the difference between the `Put` `Post` `Delete` `Get` methods by default with the help pf URL where the `API` call mentioned there.
you can invoke it from the Web via some URL to perform an action.